# Why DateTime->diff() show other results?

Tags: php, date

```
$DateStartTime = new DateTime("now");
$Day1 = '20';
$Day2 = '25';
$DateStart = new DateTime($DateStartTime->format('Y').'-'.$DateStartTime->format('m').'-'.$Day1);
$DateEnd = new DateTime($DateStartTime->format('Y').'-'.$DateStartTime->format('m').'-'.$Day2);
$Line = $DateStart->diff($DateEnd);
echo $Line->format("j");
```

This code should print count days between the dates, but in result i see symbol `j`

Tell me please, why in result we see symbol `j` and not count days in period ?

P.S.: `j` - count days without first `0`;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DateTime::diff` return a `DateInterval` instance. You can read [here](http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php) the format characters allowed. There's no `j`. What you want is

```
echo $Line->format("%a"); // 5
```